# How to design a simple (text and a shape logo) for a website

Tags: website-design, software-recommendation

All I need for my website is just a text and a shape beside the text or over it,
I googled a lot but there were no simple answers, using illustrator is just an overkill.

For example, company named "SomeX", writing the name "Some" inserting a shape, representing a big "X" symbol beside it or over the text. **I Know it would be terrible design**, I'm not selling it, it's just for personal demonstration while I'm working.

**Are there any methods or software to achieve this simply?** Write the text, add the symbol and drag it anywhere, and export the `PNG`.

Comment: This post might help you a little: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-can-i-design-a-simple-logo-without-any-prior-skill-in-graphic-design

Comment: i saw it before asking the question, my question is can i insert a shape or icon with that text? and it's not the answer i'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest Illustrator or Inkscape. You say that that is overkill, but it is not really: to make sensible logos (and you might *need the practice of this*, if you are to be a webdeveloper!) *you need to do them in vector.* I cannot stress this enough.

Inkscape is open-source, and you can do easy things without getting confused by all the more advanced options.

There are other programs of course, I am sure your computer came with some simple bitmap graphics programme. There is a plethora of them; paint, paintPro, corel-draw, irfanview.

Comment: thank you for your support, i'll try InkScape, i asked the question before deciding to learn AI or designing Logos for Websites, i bet it'll become handy one time, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Squarespace's logo generator allows you to do rather simple "logo" creations. It has a drag and drop feature, color selector and various font tools. http://www.squarespace.com/logo

Here is an example of the UI. [image: Squarespace screenshot]

Comment: Please explain in your answer what your link is about; this is good for everybody, future reference and in case the site goes down.

Comment: yes something like squarespace, any other software like this one? probably open source?

Comment: there's actually been some minor uproar about this service, as (insecure?) designers feel that Squarespace makes it even harder to sell themselves. I say it's a good way to show that good design is hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iPad, InkPad is free, and by far the quickest and easiest way to do this to your hearts content.

On a PC, or Mac, try this:

http://mudcu.be/sketchpad/

But, most importantly, I think you should read this before attempting any logo design:

http://hipsterlogo.com

Just as a precautionary measure, to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can export slide/images from MS PowerPoint to create simple graphics. It has a wide variety of shape objects and you can use the full range of fonts installed on your machine. Hubspot regularly publishes guides on how to make buttons, infographics, etc for websites using simple tools. http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/33483/How-to-Easily-Create-Professional-Looking-CTAs-in-PowerPoint-Tutorial.aspx

Comment: wow, that was great and simple, thank you, and a time saver, i wish i had more points to upvote this.